# Can I use operator<< to add element to a list?

Tags: c++, list, operator-overloading

I would like to overload operator<< that add elements into the list.

```
std::list<int> foo (3,100);   // three ints with a value of 100
```

and if I type

```
foo << 2 << 3 << 4;
```

Then the list become 100, 100, 100, 2, 3, 4.
I know there are many function that can do this implementation, and now I am learning operator overloading, so I am curious is it possible to do that and if yes how to do that?
(I want to use << to add element, no need to cout something.)

Comment: If the answer to your question is "yes, it is possible", will you be satisfied?

Comment: Definitely don't do this even if it's possible. It breaks the expectation of C++ programmers.

Comment: The simple answer is yes, you can do it.   But this is the sort of question that it is best to test out yourself first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would ostensibly write this functionality like this ([Tested on Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/qkponv)):

```
template<typename T>
std::list<T> & operator<<(std::list<T> & list, T val) {
    list.emplace_back(std::move(val));
    return list;
}
```

So the only outstanding question is whether you *want* or *need* to do this, which I'd argue the answer is You Shouldn't and No, in that order. It is generally best not to try to amend/add to the default behavior of STL containers, as doing so can lead to unexpected behavior.

If you want a list that can be inserted into with this kind of syntax, at the very least, you should roll your own (you can use `std::list` as a backing data structure, to save having to write boilerplate code) so that there's no confusion as to how STL containers can behave in your code.

### EDIT:

Because I know there's going to be some confusion on this point: it's fairly common for users to override the `<<` operator for streams. The reason why this is not considered bad practice is that `std::ostream` already has `<<` overloads for many objects, both fundamental types and for library objects, and it's more natural to overload the `<<` for this class of objects than it is for containers. And of course, all of this is contingent on personal circumstances.

Comment: "It is generally best not to try to amend/add to the default behavior of STL containers" I'd go even further. It's generally best not to try to amend/add to the behavior of code that you do not own. Rust has this built in. You either have to own the type that you are implementing functionality for, or own the functionality specification, or else it won't compile. In this case, we don't own `std::list`, and we don't own `operator<<`, so implementing this breaks expectations, and can cause maintenance headaches if the standard library decides to add an `operator<<` for `std::list`.